# How to use if condition in spinner selection - Android

Tags: android, android-studio, if-statement, spinner

In `AndroidStudio`, how do I check an `if` condition in `Spinner` selection. What is the event for `Spinner` selection. I want to redirect to the specified `Activity` of selected item in `Spinner`. Please help me. I am not asking for getting points. If you think this question is not useful. You give me minus mark, But tell me the solution. Somebody gave me minus mark and didn't answer my question.

Thank You.

I am confused. The answer given below are to check if selected or not. I want to check if item1 selected or item2 selected or 3 or 4......

Answer (score 3):

Spinner has itemSelected listener

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
    // your code here
   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
    // your code here
   }
});
```

Comment: cannot resolve symbol 'spinner'. (my spinner id is spinner).

Comment: what is the name of your spinner instance

Comment: what is spinner instance.

Comment: for example 
Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yourspinner_id);
here spinner is instance

Comment: Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

Comment: setOnItemSelectedListener in red font and @Override in red underline

Comment: where do you setting this listener to the spinner? try it in your oncreate() or somewhere don't outside the bloks

Comment: In this line - Intent intent = new Intent(this,NextActivity.class); (this,NextActivity.class) is underlined in red

Comment: @SingaramManickam plz refere this demo and implement it: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm

Answer (score 3):

you can use switch case if spinner items are countable.

```
    Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            switch(position) {

               case 0 : // for item 1
               Intent intent= new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               break; 

               case 1 :
               Intent intent= new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               break; 

             /* you can have any number of case statements */
             default :

          }   
      }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

      }
 });
```

Comment: can i use case a: case b:(because i am using string)

Comment: you can use a, b as Char but not as String.

Comment: well dude this isn't check your string or integer or char, this is only case on your position, means in case 0: means at position 0 of your spinner

Answer (score 1):

```
((Spinner)(findViewByid(R.id.yourSpinnerId)).
setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, 
int position, long id) {

    // do,whatever you want to do

   }

   @Override
   public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

   }
});
```

Comment: @Singaram Manickam, if my code is  working then please accept the answer so that other people can take help.

Answer (score 1):

Layout:

```
 <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/planets_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Activity:

```
Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           //geeky stuff goes here
            if(arrayItems[position]!=null)
             {
                //can do something like this
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //open your activity here
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.yourspinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Intent intent= new Intent(this,YourActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: (this,YourActivity.class); - this line in underlined in red line. How to solve it.

Comment: on the place of yourActivity put your Activity name where you want to go

Comment: on the place "this" put getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

```
   @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id)
{

spinner_value =  parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
Log.i("spinner_value", ".."+spinner_value);

   if(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("January"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
if (spinner.selectedItem == "Blank") { 
    Toast.makeText(context, "could not be blank" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.